# Get Highest value from items with same IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID      Severity    WorkItemSK
23636   3-Minor     695119
23636   3-Minor     697309
23647   2-Major     695081
23647   2-Major     694967
```

In here I have several WorkItems that share the same ID. How can I get unique IDs that have the highest WorkItem?

So it would like this:

```
ID      Severity    WorkItemSK
23636   3-Minor     697309
23647   2-Major     695081
```

Help the noob :) Mind giving a clue what SQL commands (again I am a noob) should I use? Or an example of a query?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Severity` can change depending on the `WorkItemSK`, you'll want to use the following query:

```
Select  T.ID, T.Severity, T.WorkItemSK
From    Table T
Join
(
    Select  ID, Max(WorkItemSK) As WorkItemSK
    From    Table 
    Group By ID
) D On T.WorkItemSK = D.WorkItemSK And T.ID = D.ID
```

The last `Join` condition of `T.ID = D.ID` may or may not be needed, depending on whether `WorkItemSK` can appear multiple times in your table.

Otherwise, you can just use this:

```
Select  ID, Severity, Max(WorkItemSK) As WorkItemSK
From    Table 
Group by ID, Severity
```

But if you have different `Severity` values per `ID`, you'll see duplicate `ID`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use select with GROUP BY: `SELECT id,MAX(WorkItemSK) FROM table GROUP BY id;`